# Can't Solve the Error - View requires API level 14 (current min is 8): <GridLayout>

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

My Code is -

```
<GridLayout 
xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:columnCount="4"
android:orientation="horizontal" >



<Button android:text="@string/btn7" />

<Button android:text="@string/btn8" />

<Button android:text="@string/btn9" />

<Button android:text="@string/btndiv" />

<Button android:text="@string/btn4" />

<Button android:text="@string/btn5" />

<Button android:text="@string/btn6" />

<Button android:text="@string/btnmul" />

<Button android:text="@string/btn1" />

<Button android:text="@string/btn2" />

<Button android:text="@string/btn3" />

<Button android:text="@string/btnmin" />

<Button android:text="@string/btn00" />

<Button android:text="@string/btn0" />

<Button android:text="@string/btndec" />

<Button android:text="@string/btnadd" />

<Button android:text="@string/btnsqrt" />

<Button android:text="@string/btncbrt" />

<Button android:text="@string/btnrec" />

<Button
android:layout_gravity="fill"
android:layout_rowSpan="2"
android:text="@string/btneql" />

<Button android:text="@string/btnpow" />

<Button android:text="@string/btnper" />

<Button android:text="@string/btnmod" />



</GridLayout>
```

And Eclipse is Giving me Error at the first line of this above Code...
**The ERROR is - "View requires API level 14 (current min is 8): "**

Please help me out..!!
I've already downloaded the API ver 14 (Android 4.0), then also I am getting this Error!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your manifest use:

```
<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="14" />
```

However, this will mean that any device running an android API below 14 will not be able to use your app.

Comment: Gr8 Suggestion..!!

But what should I do to run it on maximum API Versions...
I mean - on below API 14 Versions..

Comment: Either you write your own GridLayout, based on the one given in the Android source code, or you use the existing layout options together to try and create an arrangement that looks like a GridLayout.

Comment: writing own gridLayout means?

Answer (score 7):

Now you can use the [v7 Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7) that provides a GridLayout with compatibility for API Level 7+.

This way, you just have to use the `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` on your XML to have a backwards compatible GridLayout with native behavior.

See:

- [The official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-gridlayout)
- [A related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104914/android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout-can-not-instantiate)

Answer (score 4):

Set the android:minSdkVersion="14" in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use GridLayout and target devices with API versions below 14, you could also try the backported GridLayout library from the Android support library. See the answers to this question for details: [Grid Layout support in android API 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278358/grid-layout-support-in-android-api-10)

Answer (score 0):

Switch requires API 14, for old version, please use SwithCompat:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:checked="true"
android:textOff="OFF"
android:textOn="ON"
app:showText="false"
android:focusable="false"



witchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat)convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch_compat);
switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            textView.setText("check");
        } else {
            textView.setText("unCheck");
        }
    }
});
```

I hope help you