# android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout can not instantiate

Tags: android, android-layout, compatibility, xml-namespaces, grid-layout

been struggling with this for a couple hours, not sure why I can't get the damn thing to compile. When I try to include the android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout, I see the following error in my Preview window:

```
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout (Open Class, Show Exception)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:                 
android.support.v7.gridlayout.R$dimen   at          
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)   at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:-2)   at         
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)   at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)   at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)   at 
android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:255)   at 
android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:274)   at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)   at     
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
```

When I try to compile, I get a number of errors for every GridLayout attribute I try to use of the form:

```
view_edit_profile.xml:26: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'orientation' in package 'com.company'
```

I've copied the gridlayout module from the SDK (/extras/android/support/v7/gridlayout) into the same top-level dir as my main project module. I've set the gridlayout module as a module dependency for my main module and also added the android-support-v7-gridlayout.jar as a library for the project.

Any advice appreciated!

UPDATE (posting xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.company"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/abs__action_bar_default_height"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_med"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_med"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_edit_profile"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_med">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout_pics"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        grid:orientation="horizontal"
        grid:columnCount="3"
        grid:rowCount="3"
        grid:useDefaultMargins="true">
```

Comment: can you please post your view_edit_profile.xml code ?

Comment: xml posted, I actually got this to work by messing around with the xmlns, solution posted above

Answer (score 1):

Solution posted above, the key was setting a separate xmlns (xmlns:grid) for the GridLayout attributes. Caution, however, for some reason this didn't work until I restarted my machine. Yay Android.

Answer (score 0):

What IDE or build environment are you using? In general, you need to put a support lib JAR file in the libs/ subdirectory of your project and add it to the classpath for your build environment.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'm using Android Studio. I set up the gridlayout module as a library project and set the lib JAR as a dependency to my main module. I actually got this to work by messing around with the xmlns, solution posted above.